# Notable books on General Topology

Tags: general-topology

Searching for the Joseph Polchinski "String Theory" equivalent of a textbook in general topology.
Something that fully encompasses the important  aspects of general topology but is not too loaded with unknown set theory symbols and indecipherable acedemia language while at the same time above the average layman mathematics students ability and understanding. Also similar reads on algebraic topology as a follow up reference would be appreciated as well.

Comment: If anything Munkres settled it all in his topology book which introduces algebraic topology in the last sections. You can follow up with Elements of algebraic topology (also his text).

Comment: I've always liked Engelking.

Comment: I have always been rather fond of the second chapter of Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis." For algebraic topology, I really like Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology," which you can find here: [link](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).